# Understanding The Parabola $x^2 + 2y = 8x –7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, coordinate-systems

Now, I am reading S.L. Loney's book on coordinate geometry, and am having a hard time figuring the way he examines parabolas. The standard equation to the parabola is introduced to be $y^2 = 4ax$ where the vertex is the point $(0,0)$, the axis is $y = 0$, and the focus is $(a,0)$. The way Loney solves parabolas is by simplifying them to the standard equation by transforming the origin of coordinates. For example: the parabola $y^2 = 4x + 4y \implies (y – 2)^2 = 4(x + 1)$ is simplified when the origin is shifted to the point $(–1, 2)$. It becomes $y^2 = 4x$ Hence the vertex is $(–1, 2)$, the axis is $y = 2$, and the focus is $(0, 2)$. However, Loney has only given a limited set of examples, and in one of the questions he asks to examine in the same way and find all properties of the parabola $x^2 + 2y = 8x – 7$, I've tried conjuring an idea of my own involving rotating the axes of coordinates, but the process I follow seems to be too lengthy for Loney to intend it, moreover, it doesn't produce any result. Could someone please assist me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried completing the square?

Comment: In the example it is $x$ that is squared. So the form is $x^2=4ay,$ [You just have to switch x and y. The effect is the axes get swapped, i.e. reflection in $y=x.$]

Comment: @Camelot823: Why did you suspect axes rotation? Did you find any $xy$ term?

Comment: @coffeemath ahh, I see now how obvious it was. What about something like $y^2 = 4x + 7$? I, again, tried working out something myself; but your advise would be much appreciated

Comment: It is $y^2=4(x+7/4)$

Comment: Trivial note to above comment of @user376343 : In this case $a=1,$ and the $7/4$ is needed since want to factor out $4a=4$ to conform to the desired form for parabola.